# Error fetching command 'collectstatic':

Tags: python, django, python-2.7

Подскажите новичку, что делается не так? Создаю абсолютно новый django проект на pycharm, вызываю manage.py консоль, а там ошибка:

Error fetching command 'collectstatic': You're using the staticfiles app without having set the STATIC_ROOT setting to a filesystem path.
Command 'collectstatic' skipped

В файле settings.py из статиков только `static_url`, это нормально? Раньше если не ошибаюсь, что то еще было

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/howto/static-files/

STATIC_URL = '/static/'
MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static')
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'media')
```

папки static и media должны существовать.
Сейчас в настройках django минимально необходимые параметры поэтому их нужно дописывать самостоятельно.

Следующий вопрос будет скорее всего отдача статики.
в 'context_processors': не хватает

```
'django.template.context_processors.static',
```

без этого часть приложений работать не будет нормально, например виджет ckeditor (cked)

Далее отдаем статику из папки media, из static при разработке сама будет отдаваться. В urls.py

```
from django.conf import settings
from django.conf.urls.static import static
```

и ниже urlpatterns добавляем

```
if settings.DEBUG:
    urlpatterns += static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

Вопрос размещения на сервере в связке apache обсудили [здесь](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38383407/deploying-django-on-apache2-with-mod-wsgi-correct-location-for-django-project/38384917#38384917)

[Готовый рабочий конфиг](https://gist.github.com/leotop/9a78c10c0961cdd2bbe9633d6ebf8a5b) apache вынес отдельно на github, нужно подставить только путь, название проекта и название домена. Упрощено по максимуму за счет Define (назначение переменной чтобы не прописывать все вручную много раз)

Документацию почитаешь, ничего не понятно как делать, хотя все очень просто когда есть заготовка. В официальной документации это не доработано.